# How to ignore PDF restrictions in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing

That newer versions of Chrome follow the pdf restriction settings by disallowing it to copy text or print a pdf-file. However other pdf-viewers like Mozilla's pdf.js just ignore this settings. Is there a way to get the Chrome pdf viewer to ignore the pdf restrictions? Does anyone know when chrome changed the behavior this way?

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but still someone can find the answer useful.

I usually remove restrictions and/or encryption by printing the PDF to file in Chrome. The resulting file has no restrictions, and if it was encrypted, the encryption is gone as well.